# Automapper - Unidirectional communication of objects to list

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

I have the following model:

```
public class Foo
{
    // some fields or properties

    public Foo Parent { get; set; }
}
```

What I wanna to see after:

```
public class Bar
{
    public List<FooDTO> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class FooDTO
{
    // some fields or properties
}
```

I want to be able to use AutoMapper to map the `Parent` property of the `Foo` type to a generic `List<>` (or any other IEnumerable type) of `FooDTO` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with `AfterMap` and `ResolutionMapper.Mapper.Map` calls:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, FooDTO>();

    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
        .AfterMap((src, dest, ctx) =>
        {
            dest.Foos = new List<FooDTO>();

            var node = src.Parent;

            while (node != null)
            {
                dest.Foos.Add(ctx.Mapper.Map<FooDTO>(node));

                node = node.Parent;
            };
        });
});

var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
```